# IP canonicalization - When IP adress is typed I want it to direct to the domain name

Tags: wordpress, apache, server, webserver, apache2

I have *Ubuntu* 20.04.1 *Apache* 2.4.41 *webserver(digitalOcean)* with SSH root access and domain name form *GoDaddy*.

Running *Wordpress* version 5.4.2, everything is working fine but I can't figure out how to do IP canonicalization. I have tried several methods with .htaccess but nothing works for me. When IP address is typed I want it to direct to the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below rewrite rule in httd.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost XX.XX.XX.XX>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName test.com

 # Other directives here
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test.com$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.com$1 [R=301,L] 

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: i dont have the httd.conf file only apche2.conf where should i put these line in apacahe2.conf ?

Comment: are you using any VirtualHost in apache2.conf file? If yes then use inside VirtualHost otherwise use outside VirtualHost.